# Nodes are created with the same name and does not join to the EKS cluster via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I checked all similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find any decent answer for this issue. So main problem is when I applied my terraform. The instances up and run successfully and I can see the node group under EKS but I can't see any nodes under my EKS cluster. I followed this article [aws article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-worker-nodes-cluster/) I applied below steps but didn't work. The article also mentions about aws-auth and userdata. Should I add also these things and how? (do I need userdata I already added optimized ami?)

In summary my main problems:

1. my instances running with same name
2. my instances does not join the EKS cluster

Applied steps via aws article:

- I added aws optimized ami but it doesn't
  solve my problem:
  `/aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.22/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id` (New update during installation of node group its failing because of this image probably not suitable for t2.micro)
- I set below parameter for vpc what article say

  ```
  enable_dns_support   = true 
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  ```
- I set the tags for my worker nodes

  ```
  key = "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}"
  value = "owned"
  ```
- I specified userdata line in launch template. Below you can see my userdata.sh file that Im calling that from launch template

[image]

There are no nodes :(
[image]

`node_grp.tf` :Here my EKS worker node terraform file with policies.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_nodes" {
  name = "eks-node-group"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "node_autoscaling" {
  name = "${var.base_name}-node_autoscaling_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.name

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
        "autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity",
        "autoscaling:TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.name
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "node" {
  cluster_name    = var.cluster_name
  node_group_name = "${var.base_name}-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_nodes.arn
  subnet_ids      = var.private_subnet_ids

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = var.desired_nodes
    max_size     = var.max_nodes
    min_size     = var.min_nodes
  }

  launch_template {
    name = aws_launch_template.node_group_template.name
    version = aws_launch_template.node_group_template.latest_version
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
  
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "node_group_template" {
    name           = "${var.cluster_name}_node_group"
    instance_type  =  var.instance_type
    user_data      = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/userdata.sh", { API_SERVER_URL = var.cluster_endpoint, B64_CLUSTER_CA = var.ca_certificate, CLUSTER_NAME = var.cluster_name } ))
    block_device_mappings {
      device_name = "/dev/xvda"

      ebs {
        volume_size = var.disk_size
      }
    }
  
    tag_specifications {
      resource_type = "instance"
      tags = {
        "Instance Name" = "${var.cluster_name}-node"
        Name = "${var.cluster_name}-node"
        key = "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}"
        value = "owned"
      }
    }
}
```

`cluster.tf` : my main eks cluster file

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_cluster" {
  name = var.cluster_name

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSServicePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.name
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name = var.cluster_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster.arn
  enabled_cluster_log_types = ["api", "audit", "authenticator","controllerManager","scheduler"]
  

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
    subnet_ids = flatten([ var.private_subnet_ids, var.public_subnet_ids ])
    endpoint_private_access = false
    endpoint_public_access  = true
    
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSServicePolicy
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "oidc_provider" {
  client_id_list  = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
  thumbprint_list = var.trusted_ca_thumbprints
  url             = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer
}
```

`user-data.sh` : My userdata sh file calling from launch template

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
set -ex
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${CLUSTER_NAME} --b64-cluster-ca ${B64_CLUSTER_CA} --apiserver-endpoint ${API_SERVER_URL}

--==MYBOUNDARY==--\
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors but add them as text.

Comment: Ok, deleted error screenshots.

Comment: Haha, great, can you add them as text?

Comment: @MarkoE The error related with optimized ami. Probably t2.micro was not enough. I deleted, Im not giving specific ami id anymore. Right now I'm not getting any error. My problems right now "nodes can not the eks cluster and all node names are same"

Comment: Ok, it is pretty hard to debug like this, but there is a common mistake: do you have a connection from the instances to the internet, i.e., is there a NAT Gateway that would allow your instances to communicate over the internet if they are in a private subnet?

Comment: yes scaffolding level is working. EKS cluster, nodegroup, natgateway, vpc, subnet, sg and other stuff successfully created. Only problem nodes are not join to the cluster. I also run different some sipmle open source repo from github . I also get some result with this repo. `https://github.com/a-patel/terraform-aws-eks-workshop` . Successful everythng but not join to the cluster.

Comment: Is this resolved ? @hammer89